# Inserting a node in a linked list

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I had this exercice that asks me to create a function that adds a number in a new node to the head of a linked list based on a struct containing one integer. This is the struct:

```
struct Node
{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};
```

no problem till now. so I created one that takes 2 arguments: the integer to add and the pointer to the head of linked list, but it didn't work. this is my code:

```
void push(struct Node* head, int new_data)
{
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    new_node->data = new_data;

    new_node->next = head;

    head = new_node;
}
```

So, what I did is that I made the *new_node* point to the same node pointed by *head*, after that I make the new node the new head of the linked list. it seems very logical, although it didn't work. on the other hand, when I give the function the adress of *head* pointer instead of the pointer itself, it does work:

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{
    /* 1. allocate node */
    struct Node* new_node = (struct Node*) malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    /* 2. put in the data  */
    new_node->data  = new_data;

    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref);

    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node;
}
```

and this is the main for the function with double **:

```
int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    push(&head,7);
    push(&head,6);
    push(&head,3);
    return 0;
}
```

I understand that the second function should work, but I don't see why it is necessary to use the adress of *head* and not *head* itself. I would be glad if anybody could explain the reason to me, Thanks.

Comment: In C++ there are [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

Comment: 1) [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) & [std::forward_list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list)
already exist - *use them*. 2) a linked list is usually a *horrible* data structure for modern computers (a [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is almost always the better choice.

Comment: Choose a language, C or C++.

Comment: @Paul _@Bilal_ Invalidating existing answers by removing any of your initial tags isn't very nice. Though my answer still covers the c part of your question as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but I don't see why it is necessary to use the adress of head and not head itself.

In plain [c](/questions/tagged/c) code you can't have references (as in contrast to c++), but just pointers.

The value stored in the `head` pointer variable should be changed from within the call to `push()`, so you need to pass the address of the `head` variable to change the (single * pointer) value.

```
int main()
{
    struct Node* head = NULL;
    push(&head,7);
    // ...
}
```

---

```
void push(struct Node** head_ref, int new_data)
{

    // ...

    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = (*head_ref); // Dereferencing head_ref yields the current 
                                  // content of head

    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    (*head_ref)    = new_node; // Store the newly allocated memory address
                               // into the head pointer
}
```

---

As you were tagging your question [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) originally this isn't necessary using c++ code.

You can take the pointer parameter by reference as well:

```
void push(struct Node*& head_ref, int new_data)
                   // ^
{
    // ...

    /* 3. Make next of new node as head */
    new_node->next = head_ref;

    /* 4. move the head to point to the new node */
    head_ref = new_node; // <<<<<<<<<<
}
```

---

```
int main() {
    struct Node* head = nullptr;
    push(head,7);
    push(head,6);
    push(head,3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: References to pointers isn't very C++, but in this case it works.

Comment: I understand, But in the case of C language, it becomes necessary. my question is why is that, in this case above. I am not looking for new tricks to fix the problem but I want to understand just what is happening in using the adress of the pointer and doesn't happen while using only the pointer.

Comment: @BilalEnnouali _"but I want to understand just what is happening in using the adress of the pointer"_ Sorry, I thought I had explained that well. Passing the address of the pointer variable allows you to change the pointer value. Otherwise you'll just modify a copy of the pointer value, and your modifications aren't affecting any variable that lives outside of your function.

Comment: @BilalEnnouali --  A pointer is a value.  You pass a value to a function, that value is temporary within that function.  If you want the changes reflected back to the caller, you pass a pointer to that value.  Thus if you want to change the value of that pointer (again, a pointer is a value), you pass a pointer to that pointer.